# She wouldn’t change it, A or B (main clause is vague)

Tags: modal-verbs, will-would, auxiliary

> She wouldn’t change it, A

> She wouldn't change it, B

'A' or 'B' determines the meaning of main clause of 'she woudn't change it' even though the main clause itself is fixed. This seems to be very weird.

If this is true, all listeners will say 'Hurry up! in saying what content there will be' to the speaker if the speaker hesitates to continue his or her main clause.

> She wouldn't change it[tendency in the **past**], even though she knew it was wrong.

> She wouldn't change it[tendency in the **future**], if the sun were to rise in the west.

Do I(as a non-native English learner) really have to wait for the speaker to continue the main clause? Or the main clause above has only one meaning to the native speakers?

Comment: The first statement can be about a past tendency, habit, or decision but also a hypothetical one in the present or future. I wouldn't eat at MacDonald's even if I knew I would starve to death otherwise.

Comment: The main clause is indeed ambiguous. Even a native speaker would have to wait for the rest of the sentence to understand how the main clause was intended

Answer (score 1):

Context would allow us to determine whether it was a past tense story or speculation that we're hearing.

"I asked her to make the update, but she wouldn't change it!"

"She's already told him her position, and in my opinion, she wouldn't change it!"

If you prefer, you can see this as an "A" or "B" that comes *before* the ambiguous clause instead of after it.

There is no end of ambiguous phrases in all languages that need context to be pinned down. (P.S. note syntactic ambiguity in that sentence!)